# Column not splitting properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image: test][image: Need the bottom picture to go below the other same picture]Column not splitting properly. I need the bottom picture to go under the same picture above.

Changed col and image size

```
   <div class=" container mx-auto mt-5 p-0">
        <div class="row m-0 ">
            <div class="col-4 p-0"><a href="ourstory.html"><img src="Mainimages/Ourhistory.jpg" style="width:100%"
                        alt="Our History"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 p-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="Mainimages/Promotions.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100"></div>
            <div class="col-8 p-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="Mainimages/Promotions.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to be split? Looks right to me, col-4 then col-8, a w-100 which i assume it's just a br basically, then another col-8 after

Comment: Maybe you want rows instead of columns? If you want each picture on it's own line, you could just make each div a row.

Comment: As you can see, The promotion picture below our history. Should be below promotions

Comment: @EhFabian you coded the page that way, if you want the second promo to be under the first promo, then just move the anchor below the first promo

Comment: <div class="w-100"></div> it is below the first promo

Comment: Move the anchor from the second promo div to the first promo div, I don't know what your last comment is trying to point out other than the obvious. If you want to stack the promos then stack them in the code and no need to bother with the extra grid div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If you're looking for equal half's but you have to split the right hand side column into two rows again using divs to achieve this.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    --First left image here--
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         -- second top right image here --
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
         -- third bottom right image here --
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap `col-6` is synonymous to 50% and `col-12` is 100%

So technically to achieve your aim you do:

> |--------------------**div:col-12**------------------------------|
>
> |------**div:col-6**---------|  |----------**div:col-6**-------------|
>
> |---------------------------| |----------**div:row**--------------|
>
> |---------**img**-------------| |-**div:col-12**-|-|-**div:col-12**-|
>
> |---------------------------| |-----**img**----|-|----**img**--------|

Try the snippet below:

```css
.s50{
height:50%;
} 
.s50 img {
width:100%; 
height:100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mx-auto mt-5 p-0">
        <div class="row m-0 ">
            <div class="col-6 p-0">
<a href="ourstory.html"><img src="https://pinimg.icu/wall/0x0/los-mejores-fondos-de-pantalla-para-hombres-tumblr-wallpaper-E7f21aa5c622192c35a8e92d039623fcc.jpg?t=5cf09dc88fee5" style="width:100%"
                        alt="Our History"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 p-0">
            <div class="col-12 s50 p-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="https://hackernoon.com/hn-images/1*lduEjOI-EQltoRbmKSICeA.jpeg" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-12 s50 p-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/3dna/pages/46410/meta_images/original/00-featured-bs4-bootstrap.jpg?1561992643" style="" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your exact images sizes, but I've tried to put dummy images just show you example, If you want your page to display in the same alignment, you have to divide the div equally which sums up. You can set and divide the divs equally and make it responsive by inserting classes `col-sm` and `col-md`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
   <div class="feature-wrapper bg-primary pt-5 pb-5 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0">
<a href="ourstory.html"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100X40/000/fff" style="width:100%"
                        alt="Our History"></a>            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center text-md-left text-uppercase mb-3 mb-md-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100X50/000/fff" style="width:100%" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center mb-3 mb-md-0">
                <a href="promotions.html"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200X60/000/fff" style="width:100%" alt="Promotions"></a>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```